# Mutual information of $X,Y$ depending on $X$

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, entropy

Given $X,Y \in \{0,1\}$ and $P(X = 0) = s$, as well as: $$P(Y=0|X=0) = P(Y=1|X=1) = (1-t)$$ and $$P(Y=0|X=1) = P(Y=1|X=0) = t$$ I want to show that:

$$I(X,Y) = H(s + t - 2ts) - H(t)$$

My first approach is:
$$I(X,Y) = H(Y) - H(Y|X)$$ 
Consider $$H(Y|X) = P(X=0) H(Y|X=0) + P(X=1)H(Y|X=1) = ... \\= -((1-t) \log_2(1-t) + t \log_2 t) = H(t)$$

However, how can I show that $H(Y) = H(s + t - 2ts)$? I tried to compute $P(Y=0)$ and $P(Y=1)$ but without success. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
P(Y=0) =&  \sum_x P(Y=0, X=x) \\
=& \sum_x P(Y=0 \mid X =x) P(X=x) \\
=&  P(Y=0 \mid X =0) P(X=0) + P(Y=0 \mid X =1) P(X=1)  \\
=& (1-t) s + t (1-s)\\
=& s+ t -2 st
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use that $P(Y = 0) = E[P(Y = 0 | X)] = \sum_{i \in \{0,1\}} P(Y = 0 | X=i) P(X=i)$.

Comment: Dear Teacher, I'm so sorry for this comment..I asked question stackoveflow for help. In fact the question is mathematical..But unfortunately, no one helped.  I really need help. If I ask you for help, can you take a look? If you have a few minutes,please. Then, I will delete this comment..Thank you very much...     https://stackoverflow.com/q/50116343/8110256